# Extracting id value from a facebook url

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a JavaScript regex to extract the value of an id from facebook profile URL. For example, I have a url

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067
```

and I just want to extract the value after the `id=` which is the number `100004774025067` part only.

But In some cases I will need the user profile url from a post. For example a user posted something, and if i get the profile url link of the post then I get the link like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001883994837&hc_ref=ART7eWRecFS8mMIio66GdaH378zlJMXzisnKubh5PtgINeVwTfOil5aBIyff71OamWA
```

As you can see, after the value of `id` there's an additional parameter specified.

I only need to get the `id` value, no matter what else is in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string as a URL and extract the `id` parameter using `searchParams`:

**Without additional parameters:**

```js
var fb_url = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067";
var url = new URL(fb_url);
var uid = url.searchParams.get("id");
console.log(uid);
```

**With more parameters:**

```js
var fb_url = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067&hc_ref=ART7eW";
var url = new URL(fb_url);
var uid = url.searchParams.get("id");
console.log(uid);
```

Comment: THank you and its a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```js
function getNumber(str){
    console.log(str.match(/(?:id=)(\d+)/)[1]);
    return str.match(/(?:id=)(\d+)/)[1];
}

getNumber('https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004774025067');
getNumber('https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001883994837&hc_ref=ART7eWRecFS8mMIio66GdaH378zlJMXzisnKubh5PtgINeVwTfOil5aBIyff71OamWA ');
```

which matches any number after id